# Fourier sine series

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fourier-analysis

```
p[t_] := (1/12) Sign[Sin[428 \[Pi] t]] + (11/12) Sign[
 Sin[428*2 \[Pi] t]]
 FourierSinSeries[p[t], t, 10]]
```

I want to expand this function but it takes forever. Is there anything wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to the documentation,

```
FourierSinSeries[(1/12) Sign[Sin[428 \[Pi] t]] + (11/12) Sign[
Sin[428*2 \[Pi] t]], t, 10, FourierParameters -> {1, 428}]
```

works quickly and well. The plot

```
Plot[(1/12) Sign[Sin[428 \[Pi] t]] + (11/12) Sign[
Sin[428*2 \[Pi] t]], {t, 0, 3/428}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

gives insight into the above.